# Inconsistent ProcessBuilder Process Behaviour in Java Web Start Application

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

I have run into an issue when trying to execute a specific command using ProcessBuilder in a Java Web Start application running on Mac OS X 10.8.4 using Java 1.7.0_21 and _25.

I use the ProcessBuilder to execute the "/usr/sbin/system_profiler" command in order to obtain some information about the client machine (e.g. cpu name, # processors, etc).

The command is executed properly when launching the Web Start the application via:

- Command line javaws with URL argument only
- Command line javaws with the same arguments as Web Start-created application bundle
- Java Web Start System Preferences Cached Application Dialog

The command is **not** executed properly when launched via:

- Shortcut to Mac application bundle created by Web Start on first launch

In the case of launching using the Web Start shortcut, what happens is the "system_profiler" process creates a child "system_profiler", which creates it's own child and so on until
eventually I receive the following error (presumably when process availability is exhausted):

```
Failed to gather report from '/usr/sbin/system_profiler -xml SPHardwareDataType -detailLevel full', exception: couldn't fork: errno 35
```

Note:  The error above occurs even though "/usr/sbin/system_profiler" was launched with only the "SPHardwareDataType" argument.

[Activity Monitor showing created processes](http://tinypic.com/r/2iizfye/5)

The problem seems to be specific to the "system_profiler" command as it does not occur with a (admittedly small) random sampling of other commands.

I have also tried a few different ways to execute the command:

```
/usr/sbin/system_profiler
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/system_profiler
/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
/bin/tcsh -c /usr/sbin/system_profiler
```

All combinations give the same behaviour.

The application bundle Info.plist included the following key-value pairs under the "WebStartArgs" key:

```
 - Item 0: -localfile
 - Item 1: -online
 - Item 2: -J-Djnlp.application.href=http://localhost:8080/test/test.jnlp
 - Item 3: /Users/blah/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0/40/744be8-7ce41b1a
```

As mentioned above, I have tried launching via command line with those same arguments and the problem does not occur.

Here is a stripped-down test application that exhibits the issue:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestProcessBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] commands) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Args: " + Arrays.toString(commands));

        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands).redirectErrorStream(true);
        System.out.println("Environment: " + pb.environment());

        final Process p = pb.start();
        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputStream stdoutStream = null;
                try {
                    stdoutStream = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
                    for(;;) {
                        int c = stdoutStream.read();
                        if(c == -1)
                            break;
                        buffer.append((char) c);
                    }
                    System.out.println("stdout buffer: " + buffer);
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } finally {
                    close(stdoutStream);
                }                               
            }
        };

        t.start();

        int result = p.waitFor();
        t.join();
        if(result != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error result: " + result + " - " + buffer);
        }
    }

    private static void close(Closeable closeable) {
        try {
            if(closeable != null)
                closeable.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As a note, I also tried without the separate thread for processing the process output

Here is the JNLP file for the simple test application:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/test" href="test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Test Process Builder</title>
    <vendor>Test Vendor</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.test.com" />
    <description>Launches Test Process Builder</description>
    <description kind="short">Test Process Builder</description>

    <shortcut online="true">
        <desktop />
    </shortcut>
  </information>

  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>

  <update check="always" policy="always"/>

  <resources>
    <java href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.7.0_21+"/>
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="false"/>

    <jar href="lib/test.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
  </resources>

  <application-desc main-class="netmedical.util.TestProcessBuilder">
      <argument>/bin/sh</argument>
      <argument>-c</argument>
      <argument>/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I have also tried converting the JNLP to reference the local filesystem:

```
codebase="file://localhost/Library/Tomcat/webapps/test"
```

and the same behaviour occurs.

The only difference must have something to do with the runtime environment when launching a Mac application bundle, but I don't know what that difference might be.

Is there something wrong with:

- The way the process is launched from the Java application?
- The way the output is processed?
- The Web Start deployment configuration?
- Other?

Comment: well-phrased, well-researched, and well-asked, sir.